# Can I use GAE Cloud Endpoints from a desktop application?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I want to write a desktop application that interacts with a GAE-based web service. For Android and Web clients there is the possibility to generate client libraries automatically. Is there a way to generate client libraries for C or C++? I would settle for Python as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Theoretically all the Google APIs Client libraries allow accessing any Discovery-based API as long as the discovery document is available (which is the case for cloud endpoints) even though the functionality isn't very well documented in most cases.

See https://developers.google.com/discovery/libraries for a list of currently available client libraries.

As example of how you can use the [python client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/) with cloud endpoints:

```
service = build("your_api", "your_api_version", http=http, 
  discoveryServiceUrl=("https://yourapp.appspot.com/_ah/api/discovery/v1/"
                       "apis/{api}/{apiVersion}/rest"))

result = service.resource().method([parameters]).execute()
```

Comment: Just a small followup: Methods that are annotated with `http_method='POST'` are called slightly different, because they expect their arguments in `body` like this: `service.some_method(body  = { 'param_foo' : 42, 'param_bar': "zoo"}).execute()`

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Google App Engine Cloud Endpoints only supports generating client libraries for Android (Java), iOS (Objective-C) and JavaScript. See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/overview.

Of course you may still develop your application using GAE for your web service and write the web service interface libraries yourself in any language you choose.

Comment: most of the generators can consume an arbitrary Discovery Document as scarygami mentions. The ones you explicitly mention are really in reference to what is documented to work, but the rest will likely work just fine.

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of the details of the cloud endpoints implementation. This is useful information about the discovery documents.